# Generating Select Options using struts Logic taglib

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

Is it possible to display Select box with options filled with numbers as below in struts by using struts Logic taglib.

```
<select>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="21">21</option>
 <option value="22">22</option>
 <option value="23">23</option>
 <option value="24">24</option>
 <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

Some thing like one below

```
<logic:iterate start="20" end="25" id="Num">
  <option value="Num">Num</option>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: They are still not implemented those tags.

Answer (score 1):

Struts' logic iterate tag is meant to iterate over a collection :

> Repeats the nested body content of this tag once for every element of
>   the specified collection, which must be an Iterator, a Collection, a
>   Map (whose values are to be iterated over), or an array.

Source : [logic iterate definition](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#logic%3aiterate)

If the only purpose is to generate a simple select with the index as value for options, use JSTL instead :

```xml
<select>
    <c:forEach begin="20" end="25" varStatus="loop">
        <option value="${loop.index}">${loop.index}</option>    
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

It is not a problem to use JSTL rather than struts tags :

> The Struts team encourages the use of the standard tags over the
>   Struts specific tags when possible.

Don't forget to import the JSTL core taglib :

```xml
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In struts 2, select tag is used to display the dropdown and it takes a collection as input. More info on this can be found at

[apache official page for select tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/select.html)

and [a good tutorial on select tag](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/)